# ファーストネーム vs. 名/名前 for first name?

Tags: word-choice

I'm in the middle of doing a translation project for a website that has UI elements for filling out forms. The pre-programmed UI has 「ファーストネーム」, but I would think 「名」or「名前」 would make more sense. Which variant sounds more natural in this case?

Comment: Who are the users that will be filling out this form?  What does ファーストネーム mean in the context of this UI?  I suspect it means "given name" as opposed to "surname or family name".  If so, remember that this only makes sense for users from cultures where the given name comes first -- which is **not** Japan.  In the context of official forms, I'm used to seeing 名【な・めい】 for given name and 姓【せい】 for family name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In web forms, you can use single-kanji **姓【せい】** ("last/family name") and **名 【めい】**("first/given name"). We normally say 名字 and (下の)名前 ("(given) name", literally "bottom name") in most situations, but these are too colloquial in web forms.